# Can we Linearize/Factorize $\frac{f_1 g_1 + f_2g_2}{f_1+f_2}$ for integer programming

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, summation, factoring, mixed-integer-programming

I have $f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2$ functions which are linear. (They are basically finite summations). Can we Linearize $\frac{f_1 g_1 + f_2g_2}{f_1+f_2}$ using some sort of factorization? By Linearize, I mean write the expression a linear terms and getting rid of the denominator?

**Edit:**

To remove ambiguity. I will explicitly state $f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2$.

I am trying to solve an integer programming problem over the set of all trees with $n$ leaves.

Fix two trees $T_0, T_1$ with $n$ leaves. Fix $L_{T_s}, M_{T_s}, s\in \{0,1\}$ as disjoint subsets of nodes in the trees $T_0, T_1$ (We call them leaves (L) and masters (M) nodes). Finally, define a function $P$ that assigns each node a different value. Then I have:

$f_1 = \sum_{a \in L_{T_1}}P(a)$

$f_2 = \sum_{a \in M_{T_0}}P(a)$

$g_1 = \sum_{d=0}^{depth(T_0)-1}w_d$

$g_2 = \sum_{d=0}^{depth(T_1)-1}w_d$

Then I want to optimize the function $\frac{f_1g_1+f_2g_2}{f_1+f_2}$ over all possible trees. However, I am trying to express this in terms of a linear function to solve it with regular integer programming teqniques  instead of fraction so I can do integer programming on it.

Comment: Can you better describe what you mean by linear?

Comment: Can you just use the standard linear approximation $F(x) \approx F(a) + F'(a)(x-a)$, where $F = (f_1g_1+f_2g_2)/(f_1 + f_2)$?

Comment: Are you saying you want to express $\dfrac{f_1g_1 + f_2g_2}{f_1+f_2}$ as $ax + b$ and you want expressions for $a$ and $b$ in terms of the similar coefficients that make up $f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2$?

Comment: @tilper Yes, exactly

Comment: Or something like $af_1 + bf_2 + cg_1 + dg_2$ where $a,b,c,d$ are linear , in terms of $f_1, f_2, g_1, g_2$

Comment: it is not true for general $f_1,\,f_2, g_1, g_2$.

Comment: I edited to show my example explicitly, any help would be appreciated

Comment: @MatthewLeingang the functions domain is not the reals, it is trees.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the question better, enough to know I cannot answer.

Comment: Is $w_d$ a variable or a constant? If a variable, over what domain, and subject to what constraints?