# Integer programming of a non linear function on trees

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to create a integer programming program to run over all possible $2$ trees, $T_0, T_1$ with $n$ leaves, such that they minimize some certain cost function $f(T_0, T_1)$.

I know the standard way of building integer programming for trees is to define indicator random variables $v_{d,t}$ where its one if there is a leave at depth $d$ and node $t$ corresponds to it, however, in my case, things are a bit more harder.

My function $f(T_0, T_1)$ is nonlinear, so I am not sure how the integer programming would work, I am describing the problem below in the hopes someone can guide me in the right way:

For any tree $T_s, s\in \{0,1\}$ with $n$ leaves, We describe a subset of the nodes of the tree as leaves $L_{T_s}$ and another disjoint subset as master nodes $M_{T_s}$. Also, each node $a\in L_{T_s}, M_{T_s}$ corresponds to a separate weight $P(a)$. In addition, for each level in the tree $T_s$, I define the weighted sum $w_d$ as the sum of weights corresponding to all nodes with depth $>=d$ in $T_s$.

My objective function $f(T_0, T_1)$ is given by $$f(T_0, T_1)=\frac{\sum_{a\in L_{T_1}}P(a)\sum_{d=0}^{depth(T_0)-1}w_d + \sum_{a\in M_{T_1}}P(a)\sum_{d=0}^{depth(T_1)-1}w_d}{ \sum_{a\in L_{T_1}}P(a)+\sum_{a\in M_{T_1}}P(a) }$$

However, I am having trouble with the denominator, since it makes my function non linear. Is there any way I can linearize this integer programming problem? (I know how I would solve the problem if the denominator wasn't there).

Comment: Same question here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575924/can-we-linearize-factorize-fracf-1-g-1-f-2g-2f-1f-2-for-integer-progra

Comment: @prubin I thought that question was very general, so decided to repost here with all details asked for in that question.

Comment: Okay, but it would be polite either to close the original (if possible; I don't know if Stack Exchange lets you do that) or point out the repost, so that people don't waste time saying something one place that's already been said on the other.